# Why does Android Studio 3.0 append my new package to the previous package name?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to create new subpackages for this 'database package', specifically adding a 'main' package and a 'converter' package to the 'database' package. Whenever I do so, it does not make another package, it just changes the name of the 'database' package to 'database.main' or 'database.converter'. It doesnt do it all the time with every subpackage, but often enough to tick me off. Any ideas? Thanks.

[image: picture of file directory]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click your `project view` > Uncheck `Compact Empty Middle Packages`

[image]

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]